# When I am trying to open jyputer notebook it is showing as application notebook launch may have produced error and error is 1

Tags: error-handling

When I am trying to open jyputer notebook it is showing as application notebook launch may have produced error and error is 1

When I am trying to open jyputer notebook it is showing as application notebook launch may have produced error and error is 1 solution of this problem so that I can use notebook